# Eigen3 Error When Installing ROS on Raspi3 Jessie

Tags: ros, eigen, eigen3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I keep running into this issue when trying to install ROS Kinetic on my Raspberry Pi 3. Followed a few forums with this as the problem but the CMakeLists.txt was already updated with the answers that I found and still I am running into this error. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Pretty new with ROS and coding in general so some detailed steps on how to solve this would be great!

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindEigen3.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Eigen3", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Eigen3" with any
  of the following names:

    Eigen3Config.cmake
    eigen3-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Eigen3" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Eigen3_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Eigen3"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/eigen_stl_containers/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/eigen_stl_containers/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
<== Failed to process package 'eigen_stl_containers': 
  Command '['/opt/ros/kinetic/env.sh', 'cmake', '/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src/eigen_stl_containers', '-DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/eigen_stl_containers', '-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/kinetic', '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release', '-G', 'Unix Makefiles']' returned non-zero exit status 1

Reproduce this error by running:
==> cd /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/eigen_stl_containers && /opt/ros/kinetic/env.sh cmake /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src/eigen_stl_containers -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/eigen_stl_containers -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/kinetic -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -G 'Unix Makefiles'

Command failed, exiting.
```

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253964/eigen3-error-when-installing-ros-on-raspi3-jessie/) by [cwmacier](https://answers.ros.org/users/29281/cwmacier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-02-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [burf2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/28716/burf2000/) on 2017-02-07**:
There are a few posts on this, I think I gave up with trying to fix it and went back to Indigo however here is the post with some info http://answers.ros.org/question/250727/error-findeigen3cmake-during-install-kinetic-on-rpi/#251434

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm not sure if you managed to resolve your build issue but if you are willing to start over, we have a Python Fabric script that sets up ROS Kinetic (as well as OpenCV too) on a new Jessie Lite image on a Raspberry Pi 3.

Check out [more info here](http://blog.rosbots.com/post/157107617908/rosbots-ros-opencv-setup-open-source-github?src=ros).  More than happy to answer questions is you have.

Cheers
Jack

---

Originally posted by [jackp510](https://answers.ros.org/users/21833/jackp510/) with karma: 61 on 2017-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0